# ListView background strangely scales

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

I want to apply custom background to my ExpandableListView.
The ExpandableListView is inside the slidingMenu.

Here is the styles:

```
<style name="Widget.SlidingMenu.ExpandableListView" parent="android:Widget.ExpandableListView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/sliding_menu_background</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/menu_divider</item>
    <item name="android:childDivider">@drawable/menu_divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">4px</item>
</style>
```

This is background image:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_noise"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:dither="true"
        />
```

But the problem is that sometimes my background gets scaled and repeated like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6129677/bad_bg.JPG

And sometimes everything is good:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6129677/good_bg.JPG

Here is the background that should be repeated:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6129677/menu_noise.png

I cannot understand what is the problem behind this.
Please give me a clue.

Comment: menu noise should be the background for the cell

Comment: @blackbelt, why? and what to do if list doesn't fill whole area? leave it black? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in older versions of Android. The easiest way to work around this problem is to set the tile mode from code. After you create your ExpandableListView, simply get its background drawable and change the tile mode:

```
View myListView = findViewById(...);
((BitmapDrawable) myListView.getBackground()).setTileModeXY(
    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```